# Nth word of a string using js Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

for this, the string is:

```
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
```

how do you select the nth word in this string?

a word in this case is a group of one or more characters, either preceded, succeeded, or surrounded by a whitespace.

Comment: As seen by the answers below, this is much easier in pure javascript without any regex involved. *Must* it use regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the answers suggesting to not use regular expressions, here's a regex solution:

```js
var nthWord = function(str, n) {
    var m = str.match(new RegExp('^(?:\\w+\\W+){' + --n + '}(\\w+)'));

    return m && m[1];
};
```

You may have to adjust the expression to fit your needs. Here are some test cases https://tinker.io/31fe7/1

Answer (score 4):

I would use `split` for this -

```
var str = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten";

nth = str.split(/\s+/)[n - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function getWord(str,pos)
    {
        var get=str.match(/\S+\S/g);
        return get[pos-1];
    }




    //Here is an example
    var str="one two three four five     six seven eight nine ten    ";
    var get_5th_word=getWord(str,5);
    alert(get_5th_word);
```

Its simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just split on the spaces, and grab the Xth element.

```
var x = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten';
var words = x.split(' ');
console.log(words[5]); // 'six'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Regex-only solution, but I daresay the other answers will have a better performance.

```
/^(?:.+?[\s.,;]+){7}([^\s.,;]+)/.exec('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten')
```

I take (runs of) whitespaces, periods, commas and semicolons as word breaks. You might want to adapt that. The `7` means `Nth word - 1`.

To have it more "dynamic":

```
var str = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten';
var nth = 8;
str.match('^(?:.+?[\\s.,;]+){' + (nth-1) + '}([^\\s.,;]+)'); // the backslashes escaped
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WCwFQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on spaces, and then access it as an array:

```
var sentence = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten';
var exploded = sentence.split(' ');

// the array starts at 0, so use "- 1" of the word
var word = 3;
alert(exploded[word - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten".split(" ");
var nthWord = words[n];
```

of course, you need to check first that the nth word exists..

Answer (score 0):

```
var nthWord = function(str, n) {
    return str.split(" ")[n - 1]; // really should have some error checking!
}

nthWord("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 4) // ==> "four"
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting things is not really what you should use a regex for, instead try maybe splitting the string based on your delimiter (space in your specific case) and then accessing the n-1th index of the array.

Javascript code :

```
 >"one two three four".split(" ");
 ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
 >"one two three four".split(" ")[2];
 >"three"
```